# Asymptotic evaluation of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

I am reading a paper in which the authors derive the asymptotics for the following series:
$$
\sum_{k=0;\,k+=2}^{N(1+m)-2}\left(1-\frac{k}{2}\log{\frac{k+2}{k}}\right)\sim \frac{1}{2}\log{\left(\pi N(m+1)\right)+\mathcal{O}(1/N)}\,,
$$
where $m$ is a real number and $-1\le m\le 1$.
For completeness I report here what they write about this formula: "*where the last line can be obtained by recognizing that
the sum can be written as a convergent part plus a divergent sum which is the harmonic number, and then using
the asymptotic expression of the latter*".

I am looking for an argument to get the result they provide, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It can help in questions such as this to provide a citation or hyperlink to the original paper.

Answer (score 2):

$$S_p=\sum_{k=0}^{p}\left(1-\frac{k}{2} \, \log \left(\frac{k+2}{k}\right)\right)$$
$$S_p=1+p+\log (\Gamma (p+3))+\frac{1}{2} \left(\zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,p+1)-\zeta^{(1,0)}(-1,p+3)\right)$$

Expanding for large values of $q$
$$\zeta^{(1,0)}(-1,q)=\frac{1}{4} q^2 (2 \log (q)-1)-\frac{1}{2} q \log (q)+\frac{1}{12}
   (\log (q)+1)+$$ $$\frac{1}{720 q^2}-\frac{1}{5040 q^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^6}\right)$$

Using the above and continuing with Taylor expansion
$$S_p=\log \left( p\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{e}}\right)+\frac{11}{6 p}-\frac{7}{4 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Trying for $p=1000$, the result is in an absolute error of $2.29\times 10^{-9}$.

Comment: Thanks! As I wrote in the question the sum is only for even $k$, but this is not a big issue. I didn't know the generalization of the Zeta function, as you wrote, so that I tried to compute the partial sum on Mathematica getting exactly your result. On the other hand I was looking for an argument without using softwares, maybe using series representation of these functions, but I don't really know how, thanks anyway!

Comment: @GiancarloCreanza. I am sorry ! I misread the formula (I am blind).

Comment: No problem! It is not difficult to find the result for $k$ only even

Answer (score 1):

Suggested method: Using the quadratic approximation $\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}2 + O(x^3)$, rewrite
$$
\log\frac{k+2}k = \log\biggl( 1+\frac2k \biggr) = \frac2k - \frac2{k^2} + O\biggl( \frac1{k^3} \biggr)
$$
and examine the sum that results.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with your suggestion but it gives only the most divergent part, while I was trying to get the same result of the authors (for example, with your suggestion, I cannot find the $\pi$ as they show).

Comment: You're right, this method only gets the leading term as a function of $N$, not the constant.